# Extract short .bib file from paper

Tags: bibdesk

I have created an article with a bibliography (natbib + BibDesk, using commands `\citet` and `\citep`). Since I have to submit the .tex file, and my master file.bib is very big, I need a .bib file containing just the items cited in my paper. Is there an easy way to do this on iMac?

Comment: egreg wrote a package which could be useful, not sure how to extract the entries but it definately lists them and you could use `bash` or another programme to extract maybe, hava a read of [`checkcites`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/checkcites)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is an easy way to do this.

When you run LaTeX on your .tex file, it generates an .aux file in the same folder.

In [BibDesk](https://bibdesk.sourceforge.io/) and [Better BibTeX for Zotero](https://retorque.re/zotero-better-bibtex/) and [JabRef](https://www.jabref.org/) (and perhaps in other reference management software as well), there is a command that selects or exports all the bibliography items that are cited in an .aux file.

In BibDesk, the relevant command is the menu item **Database → Select Publications from .aux File** (*or* simply drag the .aux file onto the main table of publications). In Better BibTeX for Zotero, the command is **Tools → Scan BibTeX AUX file for references**. In JabRef, the command is **Tools** → **New subdatabase based on AUX file**.

Then export the selected items to a new .bib file.

If you prefer to use the command line, Gerd Neugebauer's multipurpose [BibTool](https://ctan.org/pkg/bibtool) could be a good choice, as it provides a simple command-line option for the task: `bibtool -x document.aux -o document.bib`.

Comment: By the way, the .aux file command is useful for other purposes: I also use the command in BibDesk to help create a static group for each of the works I've written containing the bibliographic items that the paper cites, so that when I select a bibliographic item in the main table of BibDesk I can see all of my works that cite it highlighted in the list of static groups in the sidebar.

Answer (score 1):

There are other approaches as well, including a short [Python script](https://github.com/jamestrimble/remove-unused-citations) I have successfully used in the past.